# Какие свойства по умолчанию имеет ссылка (a)?

Tags: css

При стилизации ссылок всегда указываю для них следующие свойства:

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    outline: none;
}
```

Во всех ли браузерах ссылка по умолчанию подчеркнута? Нужно ли дополнительно прописывать подчеркивание для ссылки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию, ссылки во всех браузерах выглядят следующим образом:

- непосещенная ссылка подчеркнута и синяя
- посещенная ссылка подчеркнута и фиолетовая
- активная ссылка подчеркнута и красная.

Нужно ли дополнительно прописывать подчеркивание для ссылки? На данный момент это необязательно, но нам неизвестно, как в будущем браузеры будут обрабатывать отображение ссылок по умолчанию - мало ли что придет в голову их разработчикам.

Вот, к примеру, отрывок из Normalize.css

```
 /**
 * 1. Убираем серый фон активных ссылок в IE 10.
 * 2. Убираем разрывы в подчеркивании ссылок для iOS 8+ and Safari 8+.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Убираем обводку на сфокусированных ссылках, которые активны или наведены (Hover) во всех браузерах
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0;
}
```